# When does the Dream World reset?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I was playing in the Dream World and when it reached 1 hour, it closed and reset the allowed entry time.

But today I entered just to check my berry farm, finished and left. The time it didn't reset.

How does the time resetting in the Dream World work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the Dream World, you have one hour. If you leave before the hour is up by choosing the option "Exit and continue sleeping", you can re-enter the DW any time within that hour. After an hour is up, whether you are in the DW or not at the time you will not be able to re-enter until 24 (or possibly 23) hours have passed.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks =) Too bad that you answer it today and not tomorow... I was hoping for [tumbleweed badge](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) in this question (besides the answer).

Comment: Haha, sorry mate :)